# Need help creating a points-based attendance google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I'm new to using Google sheet formulas, so I would really appreciate help/advice.  I'm trying to set up a sheet that uses a points-based system to track attendance - basically subtracting a point for every call off but giving a point back after 90 days without a call off.

SAMPLE with Editor Privilages - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OviVvyveoS9G_7QdsGZ4ksZxCMuaWP-zk2KzDwDNDBo/edit?usp=sharing

What I've set up so far starts with every employee (column A) having 4 points (column B).  The number of times each employee calls off, and the dates they call off are recorded (columns C-F).  The employee's current points (column G) reflect that they lose a point every time they call off (column B minus C), and column H shows the most recent call off date (using formula `MAX(FILTER(D4:F4,DATEVALUE(D4:F4)))`.  The manager would fill in these columns on the date of each call off.  Column I displays the date that is 90 days from the latest call off (using formula `=IF(ISDATE(H4), H4+90, ""))`.  My first problem is that I need to add a point back to the employee's "score" if they do not call off for 90 days after the most recent call off (column J).  I don't even need the column, but I need the employees' actual current score (column G) to reflect the addition of a point.  The more complicated problem is that I need one of the "call off dates" to disappear after 90 days without a call off and a point to be subtracted from the number of call offs (column C) in order for the math to continue working.

I was trying to use google sheets to simplify tracking this type of system, but I am probably overthinking and over complicating the entire thing.   I'm very open to any simple solutions or suggestions to make the overall points system work.  I tried to search the site for answers but couldn't find anything this specific.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Your post is a copy of [Setting up a points-based attendance sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/230195208). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: While a link to an external spreadsheet might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained, this means that the question should include a description of the relevant parts of the spreadsheet, including its settings, sample data for input and the corresponding expected result, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to insert a `'Call offs'` sheet where you log all call-offs chronologically, like this:

| Timestamp | Name of employee | Date of absence | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/1/2023 14:40:50 | Pat | 5/1/2023 | Child sick |
| 5/9/2023 11:01:39 | Joe | 5/9/2023 | Wedding |
| 6/12/2023 9:17:11 | Lou | 6/12/2023 | Jury duty |
| 7/26/2023 12:14:40 | Joe | 7/26/2023 | Honeymoon |
| 8/1/2023 20:17:18 | Laurie | 8/1/2023 | Giving birth |
| 8/13/2023 13:31:35 | Joe | 8/13/2023 | Medical |
| 8/13/2023 14:42:00 | Lou | 8/13/2023 | Medical |
| 8/14/2023 9:56:33 | Joe | 8/14/2023 | Funeral |

The "points system" can then count up-to-date points like this:

```
=let( 
  callOffs, ifna(filter( 
    to_text('Call offs'!C$2:C) & ": " & 'Call offs'!D$2:D, 
    'Call offs'!B$2:B = A2, 
    'Call offs'!C$2:C > today() - 90 
  )), 
  points, 4 - counta(callOffs), 
  list, join(", ", callOffs), 
  hstack(points, list) 
)
```

The results look like this:

| Employee | Current Points | Call-offs within the past 90 days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dweezil | 4 |  |
| Bob | 4 |  |
| Kelly | 4 |  |
| Tim | 4 |  |
| Sally | 4 |  |
| Laurie | 3 | 8/1/2023: Giving birth |
| Tommy | 4 |  |
| Ashley | 4 |  |
| Chris | 4 |  |
| Pat | 4 |  |
| Joe | 1 | 7/26/2023: Honeymoon, 8/13/2023: Medical, 8/14/2023: Funeral |
| lou | 2 | 6/12/2023: Jury duty, 8/13/2023: Medical |
| Jenny | 4 |  |

An easy way to fill the `'Call offs'` sheet is to create a [create a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) and set its form response destination to the call-offs spreadsheet.

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OviVvyveoS9G_7QdsGZ4ksZxCMuaWP-zk2KzDwDNDBo/edit#gid=95580142).